# Why fork() close one of the file descriptor by dup2()

Tags: c, linux, fork, dup

I wrote code to get sense of dup2().

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int fdold,fdnew;
    fdold = fileno(fp);
    fdnew = dup2(fdold,fdnew);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

the lsof shows 2 opened file descriptors (/workspace/source/throw.cpp is the arguements passed in)

```
/workspace/source/thread$ lsof -p 20779
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
dup2    20779  wto  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 946031 /workspace/source
dup2    20779  wto  rtd    DIR    8,1     4096      2 /
dup2    20779  wto  txt    REG    8,1     8672 950259 /workspace/source/dup2
dup2    20779  wto  mem    REG    8,1  1852120 135869 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
dup2    20779  wto  mem    REG    8,1   149312 135845 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
dup2    20779  wto    0u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
dup2    20779  wto    1u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
dup2    20779  wto    2u   CHR  136,4      0t0      7 /dev/pts/4
dup2    20779  wto    3r   REG    8,1      653 951057 /workspace/source/throw.cpp
dup2    20779  wto *767r   REG    8,1      653 951057 /workspace/source/throw.cpp
```

BUT, while I fork() it to 2 processes(code as below), there's only one /workspace/source/throw.cpp opened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int fdold,fdnew;
    fdold = fileno(fp);
    //fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC,fdold);
    fdnew = dup2(fdold,fdnew);
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        waitpid(pid, WNOHANG, NULL);
        printf("parent exit\n");    
    } else {
        while (1) {
            sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. Question1: What caused the dup()d fd being closed?
2. Question2: I looked into FD_CLOEXEC in manual, but don't set it by fcntl(). Does fopen() set it automatically? and does this flag impact on not only fork but exec families?
3. Question3: After I replaced dup2 by dup, the result shows 2 fds as my expectation. 
   as manual said:

   > "dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary".

   Does it mean close newfd before dup, if the newfd is opened already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a bug (uses the value of `fdnew` before setting it), so its behavior will be unpredictable. Fix the bug before you try to understand what the program is doing. Also, you should check the return value of `dup2` to see if it succeeded.

Comment: You are right. I dont get right understanding of dup, the fdnew and fdold are required to be valid file descriptors.